# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'billerFilesTrackingFilter[0]'

Tags: java, spring

i am trying to display a list of bean in input spring:
here my jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="billerFileTrackingFilter" items="${command.billerFilesTrackingFilter}" varStatus="status">
<c:out value="${billerFileTrackingFilter.cron}"/>
<tr>
    <td class ="td-table"><br><input:input cssClass="grayBox" path="billerFilesTrackingFilter[${status.count - 1}].cron" /></td>
    <td class ="td-table"><br><input:input cssClass="grayBox" path="billerFilesTrackingFilter[${status.index}].gracePeriod" id="gracePeriod${status.index}"  elment-type="input" cssStyle="width: 50%"/></td>
    <td class ="td-table"><br><input:input cssClass="grayBox" path="billerFilesTrackingFilter[${status.index}].notifiedEmails" id="notifiedEmails${status.index}"  elment-type="input" cssStyle="width: 50%"/></td>
    <td> <input:select path="billerFilesTrackingFilter[${status.index}]fileIdentifier" id="filesId${status.index}" items="${filesId}" multiple="false"></input:select></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

which billerFilesTrackingFilter is a list of bean in the command.
the c:out works correctly but i got the error when trying the use it in the input:input

---

and BillerFileTrackingFilterBean is:

```
public class BillerFileTrackingFilterBean {

private String _fileIdentifier;
private String _cron;
private int _gracePeriod;
private String _notifiedEmails;
private String _action = "edit";

public BillerFileTrackingFilterBean() {
}

public BillerFileTrackingFilterBean(String fileIdentifier, String cron, int gracePeriod, String notifiedEmails) {
    _fileIdentifier = fileIdentifier;
    _cron = cron;
    _gracePeriod = gracePeriod;
    _notifiedEmails = notifiedEmails;
}

public String getFileIdentifier() {
    return _fileIdentifier;
}

public void setFileIdentifier(String fileIdentifier) {
    _fileIdentifier = fileIdentifier;
}

public String getCron() {
    return _cron;
}

public void setCron(String cron) {
    _cron = cron;
}

public int getGracePeriod() {
    return _gracePeriod;
}

public void setGracePeriod(int gracePeriod) {
    _gracePeriod = gracePeriod;
}

public String getNotifiedEmails() {
    return _notifiedEmails;
}

public void setNotifiedEmails(String notifiedEmails) {
    _notifiedEmails = notifiedEmails;
}

public String getAction() {
    return _action;
}

public void setAction(String action) {
    _action = action;
}
}
```

ignore the action i added it afte.
thanks

Comment: Please add your command POJO and is this typo: `path="billerFilesTrackingFilter[${status.index}]fileIdentifier` or did you forgot about the dot?

Comment: And could you show you controller too ?

Comment: You can edit your question. Don't posts new details as answers.